# Connection pool timeout in cloudant ( via ektorp)

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant, ektorp

I am using cloudant and ektorp for DB operations in my java application. When I try to do a load test for 100 users (concurrent hits), it throws

```
Caused by: org.ektorp.DbAccessException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection
        at org.ektorp.util.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:19)
        at org.ektorp.http.StdHttpClient.executeRequest(StdHttpClient.java:146)
```

Following is my couchdb.properties file

```
url=https://myaccount.cloudant.com:443
host=https://myaccount.cloudant.com
port=443
username=myusername
password=mypassword
relaxedSSLSettings=true
enableSSL=true
maxConnections=100
connectionTimeout=3000
socketTimeout=30000
autoUpdateViewOnChange=true
cleanupIdleConnections=true
```

I am using the following code for creating connector

```
CouchDbConnector dbConnector = couchdbInstance.createConnector(
                    xxxx,true);
dbConnector.queryView(query,test.class);
```

Please help me understand why I get connection timeout and what param i might need to change inorder to fix this

Comment: You set `maxConnections=20`, but are testing for 100 concurrent connections. I've never used ektorp, but how does it handle more concurrent connections than you've allowed to exist?

Comment: Yes I have changed it to 100 now. 
`maxConnections=100
connectionTimeout=3000
socketTimeout=30000` is my current config

Comment: Did that fix it? (editing your question now to reflect your changes...)

Comment: No garbados.. how it works is, it creates connections to DB and they are being re-used in the connection pool. In my application I have 2 couch DB databases and one couchDB document to be updated/created. So even if its 100 http client hits, internally it requires connectos to couch DB. So there comes the timeout issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, multitenant Cloudant accounts are limited to 30 concurrent connections per backend node (typically 3, so 90 concurrent connections). If you need more, reach out to the team at `support@cloudant.com` and we can increase your concurrent connections limit.

Comment: Thanks @garbados. So my doubt here is when I have 200 concurrent hits to application, should I make no.of connections to 200? and if the number of threads increase, Should I keep increasing connections too??

Comment: Yep! If you need N concurrent connections, you maximum ought exceed N. Normally we'll increase your connection limit well beyond your immediate need, so you have leeway to grow and experiment.